# Is store array in database in efficient way?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a column called `langs` in the `users` table that contains the languages that the user chose to make the website show only the text translate based on the langs that the user had chosen.
like

```
john doe - ['en','le']
```

Does store an array in the database is the right way? if not what is the datatype should I use?

Comment: "The right way" depends on exactly how you're going to use the data and what alternative  ways if any might be better for your specific set of circumstances. `$_SESSIONS` might be as good, for instance, but it depends on your use-case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: @Martin  I do not want to the user change them from the browser!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The right way" is often an opinionated thing, as an argument could be made that this approach may be "simpler" for small applications with few use cases.  But if you're asking how to further normalize the database then you're looking for three tables:

- Languages
- Users
- UserLanguages

The third is what supports the many-to-many relationship between `Users` and `Languages`.  For example, consider the `Languages` table:

```
id | code
---------
 1 | en
 2 | le
 3 | es
```

And the `Users` table:

```
id | username
-------------
 1 | bob
 2 | sally
```

Then if `bob` wants to select the languages `en` and `le`, then the `UserLanguages` table would have:

```
id | userId | languageId
--------------------------
 1 |  1      |  1
 2 |  1      |  2
```

An argument can be made that `UserLanguages` doesn't need the `id` column, since the combination of `userId` and `languageId` creates a natural key.  That's up to your own preference, or possibly to whatever ORM or other tool(s) you may be using.

But the point is that the relationship between a `User` and a `Language` is itself an entity in the relational data.  Changing language selections would simply involve updating that table.

Comment: That is awesome explanation, big respect :)